# reputation change and total reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation-leagues

Am I seeing this right? I noticed a small thing above my reputation gains saying top %... this week/month, and when I clicked on the link I seen this to the side:

> ```
> Total Reputation
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Total Rep |Users
> 100,000+  |55
> 50,000+   |192
> 25,000+   |591
> 10,000+   |2,186
> 5,000+    |4,379
> 3,000+    |6,781
> 2,000+    |9,029
> 1,000+    |13,693
> 500+      |18,610
> 200+      |23,397
> 1+        |1,027,980
> ```

So if you have over 5K in reputation on SO your one of only less than five thousand people total in the world who has that much reputation?

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2012-04-15/997939#997939

Comment: p.s +1 for my fancy table! :P

Answer (score 5):

Not quite. That table represents only those who have earned reputation this week.

You have to look at the all-time list, which has slightly more—5,141:

```
Total Rep*    Users
--------------------
100,000+        55
50,000+        192
25,000+        598
10,000+       2,304
5,000+        5,141
3,000+        9,025
2,000+       13,644
1,000+       26,081
500+         45,871
200+         76,612
1+          927,370
```

You can see the exact cut off here
https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=103&pagesize=50

Comment: Hmm. What cut-off is that link showing? Everybody I see there has ~13,000 reputation, not >5,000.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Its supposed to be the 103 page of the all time list sorted by total rep with 50 users per page

Comment: Ah, I was only showing 15 per page. I guess it remembers your last-used setting. Fixed the link.